# Interpreting Granger causality test's results

Tags: time-series, causality, granger-causality

I'm trying to educate myself on Granger Causality. I've read the posts on this site and several good articles online.  I also came across a very helpful tool, the [Bivariate Granger Causality - Free Statistics Calculator](http://www.wessa.net/rwasp_grangercausality.wasp), that allows you to enter your time series and calculate the Granger Stats.  Below, is the output from the sample data included on the site. I have also taken a crack at interpreting the results.

My Questions:

- Is my interpretation directionally correct?
- What key insights have I overlooked?
- Also what is the meaning and interpretation of the CCF charts?  (I'm assuming CCF is cross correlation.)

Here are the results and plots that I have interpreted:

```
Summary of computational transaction
Raw Input   view raw input (R code)
Raw Output  view raw output of R engine
Computing time  2 seconds
R Server    'Herman Ole Andreas Wold' @ wold.wessa.net

Granger Causality Test: Y = f(X)
Model   Res.DF  Diff. DF    F   p-value
Complete model  356         
Reduced model   357 -1  17.9144959720894    2.94360540545316e-05

Granger Causality Test: X = f(Y)
Model   Res.DF  Diff. DF    F   p-value
Complete model  356         
Reduced model   357 -1  0.0929541667364279  0.760632773377753
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

My interpretation:

- Test was based upon 357 data points and was performed with a lag value of 1
- The p-value of 0.0000294 means I can reject the null hypothesis that x does not cause y for the Y = f(x).
- The p-value of .76 allows me to accept the null for X = f(Y)
- The fact that first hypothesis was rejected and second accepted is a good thing
- I'm a little rusty on my F-test so I don't really have anything to say on this for now.
- I'm also not sure how to interpret the CCF graph.

I really appreciate it if any of you who are well versed with Granger-causality could let me know if I'm interpeting this correctly and also fill in some of the blanks.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Caveat*: I'm not particularly well-versed in Granger causality, but I am generally statistically competent and I have read and mostly understood [Judea Pearl's *Causality*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052189560X), which I recommend for more info.

> Is my interpetation directionaly correct

Yes. The fact that first hypothesis was rejected and second was not means that you can use $X$ to forecast $Y$.

> What key insights have I overlooked

The really important thing to know in terms of key insights is that Granger-causation is only equivalent to causation (in the more common use of the term) under a fairly restrictive assumption, viz, that there are no other potential causes. If this assumption is not satisfied then Granger-causality is actually Granger-usefulness-for-forecasting. For example, if there is a variable $Z$ that causally influences both $X$ and $Y$, then the conclusion that $Y$ Granger-causes $X$ can be explained as the influence of $Z$ being felt in $Y$ before it's felt in $X$.

> The p-value of .76 allows me to accept the null for X = f(Y)

*Warning: esoteric bullshtatistical blathering follows.* Technically, in the test of $X = f(Y)$ you can't "accept the null". You can "fail to reject the null" -- that is, you didn't find evidence that would warrant rejecting the null. This is the [Fisherian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Fisher) view. Alternatively, you can take the [Neymanian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman) view: you don't *assert the truth* of the null; you just choose to *act as if* the null were true. (Personally I'm a [Jaynesian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Thompson_Jaynes), but let's not get into *that*.)

> I'm a little rusty on my F-test

The point of the F-test is that it checks that the lagged values of $X$ *jointly* improve the forecast of $Y$ (or vice versa). One can imagine predicting $Y$ with two predictors $X_1$ and $X_2$ where $X_2$ is just $X_1$ with a bit of added noise. The F-test would compare a model with just $X_1$ (or just $X_2$) with the model containing both and find no evidence of improved prediction in the larger model.

> I'm also not sure how to interpret the CCF graph

The plots of the auto-correlation and cross-correlation functions provide a rough graphical equivalent to the t-tests used in the testing procedure. In order to understand what is being plotted, it's first necessary to understand correlation as a measure of the linear relationship between two random variables. The cross-correlation function is just the correlation of one time series versus a lagged version of the other, and the auto-correlation is just the cross-correlation of a function and itself. Thus these plots show the time structure of the strength of the linear relationships both internally (auto) and from one to the other (cross). I can see from the autocorrelation plots, for example, that $Y$ is reasonably smooth but has no other particularly strong internal structure, whereas $X$ has an oscillation with a peak-to-peak period of about 120 time steps (because it is negatively correlated with itself at about 60 time steps).

Comment: This was a great answer.  Thanks for the effort.  I will definitely checkout the reference you mentioned.

Comment: To signal that I've answered your question, click the checkmark next to my answer.

Comment: i have a simple question on this so i dont think i have to open a new question. I would like to know if i can use granger test for the following. I have 2 time series. Lets say $Y_{t1}, Y_{t2}$. Can i test for $Y_{t1}\sim Y_{t2}$ and if the null is rejected, to claim that the two time series came from the same stochastic process?