# Interpreting Granger causality test's results – i.e. $X = f(Y)$

Tags: p-value, interpretation, granger-causality

The following is generated using http://www.wessa.net/rwasp_grangercausality.wasp:

```
Summary of computational transaction
Raw Input   view raw input (R code)
Raw Output  view raw output of R engine
Computing time  2 seconds
R Server    'Herman Ole Andreas Wold' @ wold.wessa.net

Granger Causality Test: Y = f(X)
Model   Res.DF  Diff. DF    F   p-value
Complete model  356         
Reduced model   357 -1  17.9144959720894    2.94360540545316e-05

Granger Causality Test: X = f(Y)
Model   Res.DF  Diff. DF    F   p-value
Complete model  356         
Reduced model   357 -1  0.0929541667364279  0.760632773377753
```

My interpretation is that:

(i) Granger Causality Test: *Y = f(X)* p-value = 2.94360540545316e-05
The p-value is very small, thus the null hypothesis *Y = f(X)*, *X* Granger causes *Y*, is rejected.

(ii) Granger Causality Test: *X = f(Y)* p-value = 0.760632773377753
The p-value is near to 1 (i.e. 76%), therefore the null hypothesis *X = f(Y)*, *Y* Granger causes *X*, cannot be rejected.

Is my interpretation correct?

[Related to full question in [Interpreting Granger causality test's results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/24753/32036).]

Answer (score 1):

no. the null hypothesis would be: X does not granger cause Y or the other way.
Also, you accept or reject your null hypothesis depending on the level of significance.

if P value < Significance level, then Null hypothesis would be rejected.

if P value > Significance level, then Null hypothesis cannot be rejected.

Answer (score -1):

For your specific example, as you are using F test the rejection of null hypothesis will be done as follows:

Compare obtained F_value to the F_critical, If F_value is greater than F_critical then you can reject the null hypothesis but before that you have to check P_value also. If P_value is less than Significance level (5% widely used) then only you can reject your null hypothesis.

Comment: Can you clarify why you think checking the $p$-value and the $F$-value will lead to different conclusions? As it stands your answer is misleading.